# How call a function inside another function

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm working actually in a shell script to monitor a server's resources. I have a function and I want to know: how can I call a second function inside the main one?

Example:

```
funct mainfunct(){

echo "Text to show here" **$secondfunct**

}

funct secondfunct(){
commands
}
```

Comment: Write the name of the first function in the body of the second function ?

Comment: What shell is that? I don't recognize the "funct" part.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In ksh or bash,

```
mainfunct() {
  echo "Text to show here" $(secondfunct)
}

secondfunct() {
  echo commands here
}

mainfunct
```

Generates the following:

> Text to show here commands here

Comment: It should be noted that the `$(secondfunct)` here would expand to the words resulting from the split+glob operator applied to the standard output of `secondfunct` stripped of all trailing newline characters.

Comment: That's not limited to `bash` and `ksh`. That would work in any POSIX shell (and some non POSIX ones like ash or zsh (though zsh wouldn't do the glob part and not choke on NUL bytes))

Comment: Why does it not work for me? I can only call a function the way @rɑːdʒɑ described.

Comment: @t7e you may need to [open a separate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) so that you can describe your environment, which is apparently different from this situation. Link to this Q&A for history or context if you like, but describe your setup and results and hopefully someone can spot the problem!

Answer (score 11):

```
android@localhost:~/test$ cat fun.sh
function myname {
  echo "my name is raja"
}

function call {
  myname
}
call
```