# Call a function with an argument inside a function that needs another argument

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I don't know how else to word this so I'll do my best to explain. I have a function

```
main()
{

        if [[ "$1" = "-f" ]]
        then
                ($sendFirstEmail) "$1"

        elif [[ "$1" = "-s" ]]
        then
                ($sendSecondEmail) "$1"

        elif [[ "$1" = "-k" ]]
        then
                ($sendKillEmail) "$1"
        else
                echo "valid input not provided"
        fi
}
```

That I call like this `main "$1"` what I need to do is pass another argument into the other functions inside the main function that also takes the first argument passed to it. $sendFirstEmail etc. are the names of the other functions that also take the first argument passed to them. In essence this is how I want to call the script `./sendEmail.sh -f johndoe@mail.com` Is this possible or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why are the `sendFirstEmail`, `sendSecondEmail`, `sendKillEmail` variables inside subshells?  Are those really variables or are they just functions?  (Functions don't need to be called with `$`...in fact that **can't** be)

Comment: So the argument you pass into the sendemail functions **is not** the same argument that is being passed to main?  Where does the second argument come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get first CLI argument after the options in shell scipt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257066/get-first-cli-argument-after-the-options-in-shell-scipt)

Comment: Can you show where `sentFirstEmail` is defined.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the position parameter(s) to them just like you have done with `main` however not outside the subshell.

```
main()
{
    if [[ "$1" == "-f" ]]
    then
        sendFirstEmail "$1"

    elif [[ "$1" == "-s" ]]
    then
        sendSecondEmail "$1"

    elif [[ "$1" == "-k" ]]
    then
        sendKillEmail "$1"
    else
        echo "valid input not provided"
    fi
}
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of the subshells were so I have removed them but if you do in fact need a subshell for some reason just put the parameter(s) inside it:

```
( sendFirstEmail "$1" )
```

---

As Kusalananda points out this particular example is better suited for a `case` construct rather than an `if` (see [3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs))

```
main()
{
    case $1 in
        -f) sendFirstEmail "$1";;
        -s) sendSecondEmail "$1";;
        -k) sendKillEmail "$1";;
        *)  echo "valid input not provided" >&2;;
    esac
}
```

---

Or better yet, [`getopts`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)

```
main()
{
    if getopts fsk opt; then
        case $opt in
            f)  sendFirstEmail "$1";;
            s)  sendSecondEmail "$1";;
            k)  sendKillEmail "$1";;
            *)  echo "valid input not provided" >&2;;
        esac
    fi
}
```

---

In the event you are actually trying to provide a second argument as Tim has suggested you could use the `getopts` `optarg` feature:

```
main()
{
    if getopts f:s:k: opt; then
        case $opt in
            f)  sendFirstEmail "$OPTARG";;
            s)  sendSecondEmail "$OPTARG";;
            k)  sendKillEmail "$OPTARG";;
            *)  echo "valid input not provided" >&2;;
        esac
    fi
}
```

In this case you would run `main` like:

```
main -f 'option to the -f argument'
```

Comment: `case $1 ...; esac` for less typing.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. It runs but it doesn't do anything. I want to run it as so ```sendEmail.sh -f johndoe@mail.com``` .

Comment: @Michael:  Where does the `johndoe@mail.com` come from?  Using my last example you would run your script with say: `./script.sh -f 'johndoe@mail.com'` and then within the script you could call:  `main "$@"`

Comment: Forgot to mention. The second argument is fed by a python script that just outputs an email address. So for the send*Email functions the first argument that gets passed to them is the email address.

Comment: So your python script is being run from within the bash script?

Comment: The python script runs separately. Then calls this bash script on a conditional basis. The way I have it now is that it calls three individual bash scripts, one for each scenario of email (first warn, second warn, kill) but I wanted to combine them into one by making them functions and calling the appropriate function within the python script with a flag instead of having to have three separate bash scripts that I have to call.

Comment: From within your python script you should be able to call your bash script with both arguments then.  `./script.sh -f 'johndoe@mail.com'` I'm not very well versed in python so I wouldn't know exactly how though.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do and I know it will work because it already works when I call the three separate scripts. When I run this code however, it doesn't actually send the email. Almost as if it's never getting the actual email address pushed through to it.

Comment: @Michael: Well I think you made a mistake when adding the `$` in front of the function names.  That indicates they are variables not functions.  So unless you have a variable being declared that points to the function somewhere earlier in your script you should remove the `$`'s

Comment: I got it from this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267631/how-call-a-function-inside-another-function . But your suggestion still doesn't work. Oh well, it works for now it's just a little messy having 4 scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just pass 2 arguments to your main function?

```
main()
{
    arg1=$1
    arg2=$2

    if [[ "$arg1" = "-f" ]]
    then
            ($sendFirstEmail "$arg2")

    elif [[ "$arg1" = "-s" ]]
    then
            ($sendSecondEmail "$arg2")

    elif [[ "$arg1" = "-k" ]]
    then
            ($sendKillEmail "$arg2")
    else
            echo "valid input not provided"
    fi
}
```

In this case, `$arg2` in `main()` becomes `$1` inside the various `send*Email` commands.

Comment: This did not work. Errors out ```command not found``` on the first line where the sendFirstEmail is called

Comment: you would have to have set up those variables to point to other functions or commands.  `sendKillEmail=/path/to/some/script`, for example, for those to work.

Comment: Are the `$` (in `sendFirstEmail` etc ) there because you thought you needed them, remove the `$`. I think we are assuming that these are variables, but I am not so sure that we can make this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of repeating what others have said:
if, as you say, you are calling the script as (for example) 
`./sendEmail.sh -f johndoe@mail.com`,
then you have to call

```
main "$1" "$2"
```

and change `main()`
as follows:

```
main()
{
        if [[ "$1" = "-f" ]]
        then
                sendFirstEmail "$2"
 
        elif [[ "$1" = "-s" ]]
        then
                sendSecondEmail "$2"
 
        elif [[ "$1" = "-k" ]]
        then
                sendKillEmail "$2"
        else
                echo "valid input not provided"
        fi
}
```

so the ***second*** argument to the (outermost) script
becomes the second argument to `main()`,
and subsequently the (one and only) argument to the innermost functions.

I have changed `$(function_name)`
to *`function_name`*
because you said that `$(function_name)` didn’t work.

Comment: Still nothing. I think it's because the first argument technically needs passed twice. The first is the -f -s -k which then calls the right function, but that function also needs its first argument, not second argument.

Comment: What do you mean by “the first argument technically needs passed twice” and “that function also needs its first argument”? … … … … … … … … … … … … Are you saying that `sendFirstEmail` needs to be invoked as `sendFirstEmail -f johndoe@mail.com` and `sendSecondEmail` needs to be invoked as `sendSecondEmail -s johndoe@mail.com`? That would be inconsistent with [your previous comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/526259/80216#comment973656_526261), “for the send\*Email functions the first argument that gets passed to them is the email address.” Please try to explain what you need more clearly.

Comment: The first argument that gets passed to the sendEmail functions is the email address. The first argument that gets passed to the main script is the -f -s -k. There is no second argument, they both take the first arguments passed to them individually.

Comment: OK, that’s what I thought. But now please try to explain clearly why my answer is not working for you.  (Are you sure that you changed the line in the script that calls **`main`** from ``main "$1"`` to ``main "$1" "$2"``?)

Comment: Yea I call the main function like that and then it errors out when the email gets passed to it. So it gets $1 and then the email would be $2 for the main function, right? But it errors out with a command not found on the email address. Also, if the inner functions aren't called like $function it won't even see that command as a function.

Comment: Really?  Does it really say “***command*** not found”? Because if it says “***command*** not found”, the problem isn’t with the email address, or even with the arguments at all — the problem is with the ***command***. … … … Try putting this at the beginning of your `main` function: `echo Hello`, `sendFirstEmail g-man@se.com` (unconditionally, hard-coded, ignoring the arguments) and `return`. (No, that is not a valid email address.) And then run your script. If you get the “Hello” and then “command not found”, then there’s something fundamentally wrong with your `sendFirstEmail` function.

Comment: It occurs to me that I should not have used that email address, because it might belong to somebody at Schneider Electric.  Better to use ```g-man@example.com```.  Or better yet, use your real address, so you can see whether it works.

Comment: Yea I tried my email. Still nothing. I think because I need to call the first argument of the main function then somehow within that function pass the first argument to the function within the main function it's not going to work.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you if you don’t communicate clearly. You say “Still nothing.”  — but last time you said you got a “command not found” error. So, are you ***still*** getting that error, or are you now getting no error? And, if (as I suggested) you called your `sendFirstEmail` function unconditionally, with a hard-coded argument, and you’re not getting an email, then that seems to say that `sendFirstEmail` doesn’t work, and you should fix it before you spend any more time on `sendEmail.sh`. But you’re being too vague and cryptic.